# How can I access the value of input inside yup object?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

I'm using formik in react for validation but right now I need the value of firstName inside yup.object({}). How can I access that?

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
        firstName: yup
          .string("Enter your First Name")
          .required("First Name is required"),
    })
 const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: ""
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `test` for this

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
        firstName: yup
          .string("Enter your First Name")
          .test(name for the test, validation message, (value) => this gives your value)
    })
```

Refer

1.[Using Test in Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestoptions-object-schema)

2.[Using When in Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema)